# KO Single page app. Async data calls randomly failing/not binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, durandal, knockout-mvc

I've got a single screen with multiple dropdowns. Each get populated via a web api call.
I'm in an active directory environment. I'm using the Durandal SPA framework.

[image]

At the moment I do the loading of my dropdowns on the activate of my view. EG.

```
  activate: function (data) {
            var id = data.id || undefined;
            userRole(data.mode || 'usr');

            // i added this as i was thinking i dont need to initialize the "static" dropdowns every time
            // I'm testing my code without this as we speak.
            if (!hasBeenInit) {
                lookupInit(id);
                hasBeenInit = true;
            }
        },
   }
```

[A] It seems like randomly, depending on the amount of server load (I'm guessing) **my dropdowns wont get populated**..

[B] Some of the dropdowns are dependant on the value of another.
I've I've achieved this by making use of the knockout subscribe event. and updating my observable collections.

**Javascript**

```
userInfo.BuildingCode.subscribe(function (value) {
        vm.userInfo.FloorCode(undefined);
        http.get('api/Floor', { id: value }, false)
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log('api/Floor');
                vm.lookups.allFloors(response);
                console.log(vm.lookups.allFloors());
            });
    });
```

**html**

```
<select data-bind="options: lookups.allFloors, optionsText: 'FloorName', optionsValue: 'FloorCode', value: $root.userInfo.FloorCode"></select>
```

If I had to select the building value for example, the floor dropdown must get new values.
The API call does happens, it seems like the observable array gets updated, but the values don't seem to be reflecting on the view.

**Chrome console log**

```
api/Floor main-built.js:14
[Object, Object, Object]

api/Floor main-built.js:14
[Object, Object, Object]

api/Floor main-built.js:14
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

What can i do to ensure my lookups/dropdowns get populated each and every call. As well as their execution order stays as specified.

I've tried something like this, but it just feels wrong. I've also added an async false overload to the  durandal http helper, but it didnt seem to work... any ideas? :\

```
   http.get('api/employmenttype')
            .done(function (response) {
                console.log('api/employmenttype');
                vm.lookups.allEmploymentTypes(response);
            })
            .then(function () {
                http.get('api/actionlist')
                    .done(function (response) {
                        console.log('api/actionlist');
                        vm.lookups.allActionListOptions(response);
                    })
                    .then(function () {  ... } );
```

**UPDATE**

I investigated my async call overload. Ended up being the culprit, once i fixed it, my data seemed to load constantly. The only side effect is that none of my server side data sets loads asynchronously. (Which i'm hoping I wont get crucified for).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `lookupInit` is a async call make sure to return the promise. So `activate` becomes something along the line.

```
activate: function (data) {
    var id = data.id || undefined;
    userRole(data.mode || 'usr');

    // i added this as i was thinking i dont need to initialize the "static" dropdowns every time
    // I'm testing my code without this as we speak.
    if (!hasBeenInit) {
        hasBeenInit = true;
        return lookupInit(id);
    }
    return true;
},
```

I'm still digesting the other part(s) of the question, but thought that might get you started already.

**Update**: The value of `vm.userInfo.FloorCode` is reset to undefined, but in the `select` there's no `optionsCaption: 'Please select...'` defined. It might be that ko won't update the option values because is can't find a corresponded value.

Comment: Yes, the standard they have at the client is that defaults get added to the value set, thus i couldn't/didn't add a caption. I'll have a look at  your suggestion. I investigated my async call overload. Ended up being the culprit, once i fixed it, my data seemed to load constantly... although it feels slightly wrong making the majority of the api calls async false. Would this be standard practice when dealing with server side data?

Comment: Don't get me wrong here. I was NOT suggesting to set `async=false`, instead I was suggesting returning the promise, so that Durandal knows  during `activate` when it's allowed to do further composing.
If the default it added to the value set, make sure to set the value for default instead of `undefined` e.g. `vm.userInfo.FloorCode('WhatEverDefaultValueIsReturned')`;